# openCV grabcut GC_INIT_WITH_MASK first iteration

Tags: c++, opencv, image-segmentation

He,
how can I initialize the first Grabcut with mask? In my case every time I've got this error: (-215) !bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty() in function initGMMs.
Is it possible to run the first Grabcut iteration with mask? When I'm using the first Grabcut Iteration with Rect it already works. Here is my code for init with mask (second Iteration):

```
mask = Mat::ones(image_.size(), CV_8UC1) * GC_PR_BGD; //GC_PR_BGD
// GrabCut segmentation
    grabCut(GrabCut::image,    // input image
            GrabCut::mask,   // segmentation result
            Rect(),// rectangle containing foreground
            GrabCut::bgModel,GrabCut::fgModel, // models
            iteration,       // number of iterations
            GC_INIT_WITH_MASK ); // use mask
```

fyi
The mask is initialized by the function when mode is set to GC_INIT_WITH_RECT. 
The mask has 4 "layers":

```
GC_BGD defines an obvious background pixels.
GC_FGD defines an obvious foreground (object) pixel.
GC_PR_BGD defines a possible background pixel.
GC_PR_FGD defines a possible foreground pixel.
```

(http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grabcut#cv2.grabCut)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but the result is clean and has no rectangle on the edge of the image.

1. first Grabcut init with rect
2. draw a bigger rectangle around the image by using GC_PR_FGD/BGD as color

   ```
   int xyCord = 1;
   int size = 2*xyCord;
       rectangle(GrabCut::mask, Point(xyCord,xyCord),Point(GrabCut::image.cols-size,GrabCut::image.rows-size),Scalar(GC_PR_FGD),30);
       rectangle(GrabCut::mask, Point(xyCord,xyCord), Point(GrabCut::image.cols-size,GrabCut::image.rows-size),Scalar(GC_PR_BGD),30);
   ```
3. second Grabcut init with mask